# UILabel.text with Singleton String is nil - Warning: Attempt to present ** whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift2, singleton, uilabel

I have a dummy question...

in one of my `ViewController`, I set a `UILabel` text with a String var coming from a singleton:

```
var nom: String!
var prenom: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
.....
self.nom = User.sharedInstance.nom
self.prenom = User.sharedInstance.prenom
....
print("User: \(self.nom) - \(self.prenom)")
self.labelWelcome.text = ("Bienvenue \(self.prenom) \(self.nom)")
```

the print is displaying the right user value, but my `View` is displaying Bienvenue nil nil....

any idea ?

Comment: try in viewdidappear once

Comment: same thing if I'm doing it in viewDidAppear function. my print is displayed successfully but not the copy in m UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if let nom1 = self.nom {
    print("User: \(nom1)")
}
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, but the print is ok, I can see my singleton value. My concerne is just when I'm trying to copy this value into my UILabel.text...